# Volver a la página index en React sin volver a tener que realizar llamadas a API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Mi pregunta es muy simple y sin embargo estoy teniendo problemas para encontrar una solución. Los códigos que encuentro muchos no funcionan (versiones de React incompatibles o funciones deprecated).

Tengo por el momento el componente Home y el componente *CreateArticle* . En el componente *Home* realizo llamada GET a una Api externa para cargar un listado de *-Articles-* . El usuario puede hacer click en un botón desde Home que le lleva a *CreateArticle*. Dentro de este componente, hay un botón para volver a Home. Aquí es dónde quiero implantar un método o función que cuando se le clicke al botón "volver" vuelva a la página Home pero sin que haga otra vez petición GET.

**¿O quizás es mejor que renderice condicionalmente CreateArticle dentro de Home para así ahorrarme este problema y asegurarme que no se volverá a llamar a la API por segunda vez?**

Me gustaría tenerlo separado de Home pero si no hay otra opción tendré que hacerlo así imagino.

De momento he probado con *history.push.back* etc pero dice que esta deprecated.

He probado con *useNavigate()* y funciona pero sólo 1 vez. Cuando vuelvo a usarlo (en la misma sesión) no vuelve para atrás.

Comment: ¿Que tal si colocas un enlace en el boton que te lleve a Home?.

Comment: Creo que tendrias que usar el hook de useState para guardar el stado y useEffect para realizar la llamama a la api una sola vez, mira esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938568/how-to-share-application-state-between-react-router-v4-routes

Comment: @DanielBriceño ¿ Y eso no hace que se carguen de nuevo los -Articles- ? Edito: Gracias, parece que efectivamente no hace que se carguen de nuevo! Creo que me servirá con eso gracias.

Comment: Estaría bien si nos dejaras ver tu código, para ver que has intentado y poder ayudarte mejor. De todas maneras si en Home, tienes un useState que guarde los articulos y un useeffect, si vuelves a home y no ha cambiado nada, no debería volver a realizar la llamada a la API. A no se que vaya ligada al render de la página. En ese caso useCallback() es tu aliada para evitar de nuevo la llamada a la API. Si pones código te lo muestro.